# return vs print list

Tags: python, list, printing, return

Very new to programming.
Wondering why does this example print all the items in the list, while the second example prints only the first?

```
def list_function(x):
    for y in x:
        print(y)

n = [4, 5, 7]
list_function(n)
```

---

```
def list_function(x):
    for y in x:
        return y 

n = [4, 5, 7]
print(list_function(n))
```

Comment: Return always terminates execution of a function.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27502505/4014959

Comment: I'm going to favorite this question as evidence against all the people who say new programming questions aren't well-received here or instantly get piled on downvotes. This is a well-written, well-presented question on an extremely basic topic without a single downvote.

Comment: Cool.. glad it was a good question! Stack Overflow is amazing.

Answer (score 6):

Your first example iterates through each item in `x`, printing each item to the screen. Your second example *begins* iterating through each item in `x`, but then it returns the first one, which ends the execution of the function at that point.

Let's take a closer look at the first example:

```
def list_function(x):
    for y in x:
        print(y)  # Prints y to the screen, then continues on

n = [4, 5, 7]
list_function(n)
```

Inside the function, the `for` loop will begin iterating over `x`. First `y` is set to `4`, which is printed. Then it's set to `5` and printed, then `7` and printed.

Now take a look at the second example:

```
def list_function(x):
    for y in x:
        return y  # Returns y, ending the execution of the function

n = [4, 5, 7]
print(list_function(n))
```

Inside the function, the `for` loop will begin iterating over `x`. First `y` is set to `4`, which is then *returned*. At this point, execution of the function is halted and the value is returned to the caller. `y` is never set to `5` or `7`. The only reason this code still does print something to the screen is because it's called on the line `print list_function(n)`, so the return value will be printed. If you just called it with `list_function(n)` as in the first example, nothing would be printed to the screen.

Comment: Thankyou.  I do understand that, what I'm confused about is your second sentence.. why does it only return the first one?

Comment: @Dude, because `return` returns the value and then _ends execution of the function_, whereas `print` just prints the value. The only reason the second one prints out the value is because you're calling `print` with the return value.

Comment: ah sorry didn't read the word "begins".  That makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: @Dude, sure thing. If this answered your question, you should upvote and accept the answer :). Also upvote other good answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

For functions `return` terminates the execution, therefore nothing will be executed after return.

In your case the first function **will print all the items** because there is nothing that breaks the process. However in the second function it **will return** and end the process.