# pairwise comparison of integers in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

What I am trying to do here is to compare integers within pairs.

if I have a list of pairs

[(10, 5), (6, 3), (2, 20), (100, 80)]

I would want to compare x > y for each of the pairs
and return False if any of the pairs do not meet the condition

```
def function(list_or_tuple):
num_integers = len(list_or_tuple)

pairs_1 = list(zip(list_or_tuple[::2], list_or_tuple[1::2]))
print(pairs_1)
#pairs_2 = list(zip(list_or_tuple[1::2], list_or_tuple[2::2]))
#print(pairs_2)

for x1, y1 in pairs_1:
    return bool(x1 > y1)
```

and my program keeps on returning True for the above example

I believe the program is only testing the first pair, which is (10,5)

what should I do to make my program test all the pairs in the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return statement in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864166/return-statement-in-for-loops)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312248/return-vs-print-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function with a list comprehension:

```
lst = [(10, 5), (6, 3), (2, 20), (100, 80)]
result = all(x[0] > x[1] for x in lst)
```

Comment: Or any for the opposite